Append cloned row to latest child where the button is clicked
I have a table with a button that when clicked, I save it in the DB via AJAX. If successful, it should clone the current row where the button is in, and then append it to the latest child. Saving it in the DB is no issue. My problem is purely frontend.
Here's my sample table:
no.     | button holder
-----------------------
2       | button here |
---------------------
2.1     | button here |
-----------------------
2.1.1   | button here |
-----------------------
2.1.1.1 | button here |
-----------------------
2.1.1.2 | button here |
-----------------------
2.2     | button here |
-----------------------
2.2.1   | button here |
-----------------------
2.2.2   | button here |
-----------------------
2.3     | button here |
-----------------------

The scenarios I want to cover:

If I click the button beside 2, I should be able to create 2.4 and add it right after 2.3, since the last child of 2 is 2.3
If I click the button beside 2.1.1, I should be able to create 2.1.1.3 and add it right after 2.1.1.2, since the last child of 2.1.1 is 2.1.1.2
If I click the button beside 2.3, I should be able to create 2.3.1 and add it right after 2.3, since 2.3 has no children yet.

The first level children have indicator with tr class = parent and the rest have tr class = child.
Here's my current function:
var currentButton;
var labelName;
var button_from;
function addChild(is_initial){
    labelName = $('#childlabelName').val();
    //ajax to save the new child
    if(button_from == 'td'){
        parent_id = child_id;
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'get_action':'add_child', 'header_id':header_id, 'parent_id': parent_id, 'row_content': labelName},
        success:function(response){
            if(response.success == true){
                $.confirm({
                    title: 'Success!',
                    content: 'Successfully added the new child.',
                    type: 'green',
                    typeAnimated: true,
                    buttons: {
                        close: function () {
                            if(button_from == 'th'){ //if button is clicked from the header
                                // Find the closest thead
                                var $thead = $(currentButton).closest('thead');
                                // Find the next tbody after this thead
                                var $nextTbody = $thead.next('tbody');

                                // Find the last row in the tbody
                                var $lastRow = $nextTbody.find('tr:last');

                                // Clone the last row
                                var $clonedRow = $lastRow.clone();

                                // Get the current row number from the last row's text
                                var lastRowNumberText = $lastRow.find('td:first').text();
                                var lastRowNumberParts = lastRowNumberText.split('.');
                                var newNumber = parseInt(lastRowNumberParts[1]) + 1;

                                // Update the number in the first td of the cloned row
                                var newNumberText = lastRowNumberParts[0] + '.' + newNumber;
                                $clonedRow.find('td:first').text(newNumberText);

                                // Optional: Clear input values in the cloned row
                                $clonedRow.find('input, textarea').val('');

                                // Get the header index
                                var get_index = $thead.index() / 2; // Assuming thead and tbody are alternating

                                // Get the index of the latest cloned row
                                var indexOfLatestRow = $nextTbody.find('tr').length;

                                // Update the label in the second td of the cloned row
                                var second_column_content = labelName +
                                    '<div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">' + 
                                        '<button data-id="' + response.row_id + '" data-header_id="' + header_id + '" data-parent_id="' + parent_id + '" onclick="loadModal(this,\'table\',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>' + 
                                    '</div>';

                                $clonedRow.find('td:eq(1)').html(second_column_content);
                                // Update the names and IDs of form elements in the cloned row
                                $clonedRow.find('input, textarea').each(function() {
                                    var old_name = $(this).attr('name');
                                    var new_name = old_name.replace(/_[\d_]+$/, '_' + response.row_id); // Replace the last part after underscore with row_id
                                    $(this).attr('name', new_name);
                                });

                                // Add a delete button in the cloned row
                                //$clonedRow.find('td:last').html('<i class="bi bi-trash-fill" onclick="delete_current_row(this);" style="font-size: 20px; color: red;"></i>');
                                clearFields($clonedRow);
                                // Append the cloned row to the correct tbody
                                $nextTbody.append($clonedRow);
                            }

                            if (button_from == 'td') {
                                var $closestTr = $(currentButton).closest('tr');
                                var $lastRowWithParentId = null;
                                var foundChild = false;

                                // Find the last row with the same parent_id
                                $closestTr.nextAll('tr').each(function() {
                                    var $tdWithButton = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
                                    if ($tdWithButton.find('button').data('parent_id') == parent_id) {
                                        $lastRowWithParentId = $(this);
                                        foundChild = true;
                                    } else if (foundChild) {
                                        return false; // break loop if a non-child row is found after finding a child
                                    }
                                });

                                // If no row with the same parent_id is found, find the row with data-id = parent_id
                                if (!$lastRowWithParentId) {
                                    $closestTr.nextAll('tr').each(function() {
                                        var $tdWithButton = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
                                        if ($tdWithButton.find('button').data('id') == parent_id) {
                                            $lastRowWithParentId = $(this);
                                            return false; // break loop once found
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                // Clone the row
                                var $rowToClone = $lastRowWithParentId ? $lastRowWithParentId : $closestTr;
                                var $clonedRow = $rowToClone.clone();

                                if ($closestTr.hasClass('parent')) {
                                    $clonedRow.closest('tr').attr('class', 'child');
                                }

                                // Update hierarchical number
                                var newHierarchicalNumber = getNewHierarchicalNumber($rowToClone.find('td:first').text(), $closestTr);
                                $clonedRow.find('td:first').text(newHierarchicalNumber);
                                $clonedRow.find('input, textarea').val('');

                                // Update the label in the second td of the cloned row
                                var second_column_content = labelName +
                                    '<div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">' +
                                    '<button data-id="' + response.row_id + '" data-header_id="' + header_id + '" data-parent_id="' + parent_id + '" onclick="loadModal(this,\'table\',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>' +
                                    '</div>';

                                $clonedRow.find('td:eq(1)').html(second_column_content);

                                $clonedRow.find('input, textarea').each(function() {
                                    var old_name = $(this).attr('name');
                                    var new_name = old_name.replace(/_[\d_]+$/, '_' + response.row_id);
                                    $(this).attr('name', new_name);
                                });

                                // Insert the cloned row after the last row with the same parent_id or the current row
                                if ($lastRowWithParentId) {
                                    $lastRowWithParentId.after($clonedRow);
                                } else {
                                    $closestTr.after($clonedRow);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $.confirm({
                    title: 'Encountered an error!',
                    content: 'Failed to add the new child. Please refresh the page and try again. Contact the system\'s administrator if issue persists.',
                    type: 'red',
                    typeAnimated: true,
                    buttons: {
                        close: function () {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $('#childlabelName').val('');
    
}

function getNewHierarchicalNumber(currentNumber, $closestTr) {
    var hierarchicalParts = currentNumber.split('.');

    // Find all child rows of $closestTr
    var $childRows = $closestTr.nextUntil('tr:not(.child)');
    
    // If there are child rows, find the last one and increment its number
    if ($childRows.length > 0) {
        var lastChildNumber = $childRows.last().find('td:first').text();
        var lastChildNumberParts = lastChildNumber.split('.');
        hierarchicalParts = lastChildNumberParts;
        hierarchicalParts[hierarchicalParts.length - 1] = parseInt(hierarchicalParts[hierarchicalParts.length - 1]) + 1;
    } else {
        // If no child rows, append ".1" to the current hierarchical number
        hierarchicalParts.push('1');
    }

    return hierarchicalParts.join('.');
}

The ones I really want to solve are:

the numbering
the placing of the cloned row

Update:
I tried adding a condition where if the current row where the button is clicked has no existing child, then it will just copy the number and add '.1' to it. It still produced wrong numbers.
Update 2:
I also tried to just create a function that reorders the whole tbody but it's not fully correct.
When I try to add 1.3.2 from the existing table:
1.3
1.3.1
1.3.1.1
1.3.1.2

I get:
1.3
1.3.1
1.3.2
1.3.1.1
1.3.1.2

When I'm expecting to get:
1.3
1.3.1
1.3.1.1
1.3.1.2
1.3.2

Here's my function for that:
function reorderTableRows() {
    var $table = $('#myTable');
    var $tbody = $table.find('tbody');

    // Clear existing tbody elements (optional, depending on your structure)
    $tbody.empty();

    // Recursive function to nest children rows
    function nestChildren(parentId, $parentElement, level) {
        var $children = $table.find('tr[data-parent_id="' + parentId + '"]');
        
        if ($children.length > 0) {
            // Sort children rows based on data-id
            $children.sort(function(a, b) {
                var idA = $(a).data('id');
                var idB = $(b).data('id');
                return idA - idB;
            });

            // Append sorted children rows under the parent element
            $children.each(function() {
                var $childRow = $(this);
                var childId = $childRow.data('id');

                // Find the previous sibling to insert after
                var $prevSibling = $parentElement; // start with parent element
                $parentElement.nextAll('tr').each(function() {
                    var $nextRow = $(this);
                    if ($nextRow.data('parent_id') == parentId && $nextRow.data('id') < childId) {
                        $prevSibling = $nextRow;
                    } else {
                        return false; // stop loop when we move past the relevant siblings
                    }
                });

                // Insert the child row after the previous sibling
                $prevSibling.after($childRow);

                // Recursively nest grandchildren
                nestChildren(childId, $childRow, level + 1);
            });
        }
    }

    // Start nesting from top-level parent rows (where data-parent_id is null or undefined)
    var $topLevelRows = $tbody.find('tr').filter(function() {
        return !$(this).data('parent_id'); // Filter rows where data-parent_id is null or undefined
    });

    // Sort top-level rows based on data-id (optional, depending on your needs)
    $topLevelRows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var idA = $(a).data('id');
        var idB = $(b).data('id');
        return idA - idB;
    });

    // Append sorted top-level rows to tbody
    $topLevelRows.each(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        $tbody.append($row);
        nestChildren($row.data('id'), $row, 1); // Start nesting children recursively
    });
}

I forgot to add my HTML table:
<table class="table" id="main_table">
<thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th width="300px">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><div class="header-name">Document and Records Needed</div>
            <div class="btn-holder ms-1">
                <button type="button" data-header_id="1" onclick="loadModal(this,'table', false);" class="btn btn-link add-sign p-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button></div>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>Compliant</th>
        <th>NC</th>
        <th>Observation/Non-Conformance</th>
        <th>Performed By</th>
        <th>Performed Date/Time</th>
        <th>Corrective Action</th>
        <th>Corrected By</th>
        <th>Corrected Date/Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="row-name">Verification Result for Raw Materials and Ingredients Records</div>
            <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">
                <button data-id="1" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_1" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant"></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_1" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC"></div></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_1" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_1"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_1"></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_1" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_1"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>1.1.1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="row-name">Child 1.1.1</div>
            <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">
                <button data-id="2" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="1" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_2" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant"></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_2" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC"></div></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_2" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_2"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_2"></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_2" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_2"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>
            <div class="row-name">Child 1.2</div>
            <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">
                <button data-id="7" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_7" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant"></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_7" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC"></div></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_7" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_7"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_7"></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_7" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_7"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>1.2.1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="row-name">Child 1.2.1</div>
            <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">
                <button data-id="8" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="7" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_8" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant"></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_8" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC"></div></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_8" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_8"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_8"></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_8" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_8"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_8"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>
            <div class="row-name">Child 1.3</div>
            <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center"><button data-id="22" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_22" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant"></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_22" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC"></div></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_22" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_22"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_22"></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_22" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_22"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_22"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>1.3.1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="row-name">1.3.1</div>
            <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center"><button data-id="58" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="22" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_58" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant"></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_58" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC"></div></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_58" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_58"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_58"></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_58" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_58"></td>
        <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_58"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
    <td>1.3.1.1</td>
    <td>
        1.3.1.1
        <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">
            <button data-id="198" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="58" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_198" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant"></div></td>
    <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_198" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC"></div></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_198" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_198"></td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_198"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_198" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_198"></td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_198"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
    <td>1.3.1.2</td>
    <td>
        1.3.1.2
        <div class="mt-1 btn-holder d-flex align-items-center">
            <button data-id="199" data-header_id="1" data-parent_id="58" onclick="loadModal(this,'table',false);" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-sign px-0 fw-bold">(<span class="plus-sign">+</span>Add Child)</button>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_199" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="Compliant">
        </div></td>
    <td><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="compliant_199" onclick="checkRadio(this);" value="NC">
            </div>
        </td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="observation_199" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_by_199"></td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="performed_datetime_199"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrective_action_199" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_by_199"></td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="corrected_datetime_199"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

My table can contain multiple thead and tbody.
Another approach I can think of is to save the numbering in the database and then insert it to where it belongs, but the numbering is just for display purposes only. Should I go for it?
Any help is highly appreciated.

pls add the html of table too

The initial html table is from the controller but I will update my code to show the sample table.

After cloning the row, I just called this function:
function reorderTableRows(){
    $('#table_id > tbody').each(function() {
        var $tbody = $(this);

        // Function to extract and parse hierarchical numbers
        function parseHierarchyNumber(hierarchy) {
            return hierarchy.split('.').map(function(num) {
                return parseInt(num, 10);
            });
        }

        // Extract and parse hierarchical numbers for each row in the current tbody
        var rowsWithHierarchy = [];
        $tbody.find('tr').each(function() {
            var $row = $(this);
            var hierarchy = $row.find('td:first').text().trim(); // Assuming the hierarchy is in the first <td> element
            console.log('hierarchy', hierarchy);
            var parsedHierarchy = parseHierarchyNumber(hierarchy);
            rowsWithHierarchy.push({ hierarchy: parsedHierarchy, element: $row });
        });

        // Sort rows based on parsed hierarchical numbers
        rowsWithHierarchy.sort(function(rowA, rowB) {
            var hierarchyA = rowA.hierarchy;
            var hierarchyB = rowB.hierarchy;

            // Compare each level of the hierarchy
            for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(hierarchyA.length, hierarchyB.length); i++) {
                if (hierarchyA[i] !== hierarchyB[i]) {
                    return hierarchyA[i] - hierarchyB[i];
                }
            }

            // If one hierarchy is a prefix of the other, shorter hierarchy comes first
            return hierarchyA.length - hierarchyB.length;
        });

        // Clear existing tbody content
        $tbody.empty();

        // Append sorted rows back to the tbody
        rowsWithHierarchy.forEach(function(row) {
            $tbody.append(row.element);
        });
    });
}

Worked like a charm.
Disclaimer: I only tested it up until 4 levels of children (e.g. 1.1.1.1)
